# Android 13 issue with ANR handling

Tags: android, anr

I know that the following is against all Android best practices... So please be kind with me :-)

We have a big legacy software that is not easy to be transformed. The app does do way to much things on the UI Thread. So, under certain circumstances, it comes from time to time that Android considers our app is in deadlock state. So it prompts the user with an ANR ( Application not responding -> Wait, or Close ?)
Our users know that our software is bad architected on some parts and so the click Wait...
On Android 7 to 12 it was the case that the ANR then clears itself. The mainThread is responsive again and so the app is working.
But on Android 13 this is not the case. The mainThread is responsive again, the app can be used in a normal way, but the ANR message comes back every 5seconds.

In a simple Kotlin app this can be tried out with minimal effort.

- Create an activity with two buttons and a label
- First button increases a counter and refreshes the label
- Second button has a sleep that is longer as 5 seconds ( make it 12 seconds, so you are 100% in the issue case )

If first the Sleep button is pressed and then the increase button multiple times,the app freezes in the first place and when the sleep time is over the label gets refreshed the number of times we pressed.
Then after 5seconds the ANR message comes.... Click wait.... ANR comes again.... Over and over again....

Sounds like an issue in Android 13 for us..

Is there a nifty way to clear the message queue of the main thread so Android does not try to deliver the message over and over again ?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: I think this may be an Android bug.  I've seen the same thing happen but had thought it was an app bug at first.

Comment: Yes. We think so too.. Of course ANRs should be prevented at all cost. But sadly, in our case, the cost is very high...

Comment: What do You think, is there a nifty way to clear the message queue of the main thread so Android does not try to deliver the message over and over again? I think it's impossible for a production app.

Comment: I still keep having this on Android 13 and am disappointed no one can give insight on this :( This especially makes *debugging* extremely difficult, because if you place a breakpoint anywhere in code that is run on the UI thread and you debug it for more than 5 seconds it will trigger the infinite ANR loop. It's madness!

Comment: @BokiliProduction "I think it's impossible for a production app" -> do you know if it exists for a debug app?